# Execute m file at startup

Tags: call, startup, matlab

I have a MATLAB m file, which I now manually execute after every startup of MATLAB. The file is located in a directory defined by an environmental variable. For example, if the file is `start.m` in directory `D:\Dir` then the environmental variable is `FILE_PATH = "D:\Dir"` and the full file path is `%FILE_PATH%/start.m`.

What I want to do is call this m file every time MATLAB starts, from a batch file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Read [this](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=matlab%20startup%20file&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/startup.html&ei=LeEXT4KIOqX44QScmfDbDQ&usg=AFQjCNFRRnUoMBy5r5Bby6w9w23j5aumQg&cad=rja) manual page. You could use the startup.m file for this.